# How can i get properties from child component in blazor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazor

I neet to get count from stockcomponents on
**My Parent component using child.** For this code Count got 0 but actually data having more

```
<Heading Size="HeadingSize.Is4">Count @ItemCount Entries</Heading>
<StockComponent @ref=stockComponent />

StockComponent stockComponent;
int ItemCount ;
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if(firstRender)
    {
         ItemCount = stockComponent.Count();
         StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

** My StockComponent **

```
private int count;
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if(firstRender)
    {
        Items = await db.Item.ToListAsync();
        count =  Items.Count;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
public int Count () 
{
        return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [two-way binding](https://blazor-university.com/components/two-way-binding/).
Also:

- get items in `OnInitializedAsync()`
- you don't have to call `StateHasChanged()`